# Python regex: findall() and search()

Tags: python, regex

I have the following Python regex:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"(\b\w+)\s+\1")
```

`\b`    :   word boundary
`\w+`  :   one or more alphanumerical characters
`\s+`  :   one or more whitespaces (can be , `\t`, `\n`, ..)
`\1`    :   backreference to group 1 ( = the part between `(..)`)

This regex should find all double occurences of a word - if the two occurences are next to each other with some whitespace in between.
The regex seems to work fine when using the **search** function:

```
>>> p.search("I am in the the car.")

<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(8, 15), match='the the'>
```

The found match is `the the`, just as I had expected. The weird behaviour is in the **findall** function:

```
>>> p.findall("I am in the the car.")

['the']
```

The found match is now only `the`. Why the difference?

Comment: Because `findall` returns only the capturing groups if there are any (or the complete match otherwise).

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall "If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups"

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thank you. So I have to use a non-capturing group to solve the issue? I will try it out right now..

Comment: I get a `sre_constants.error: invalid group reference 1 at position 13` error when changing my group `(...)` by `(?:...)` to make it non-capturing. Perhaps that's because using a backrefence to a non-capturing group is impossible?

Comment: @K.Mulier: well, you can't do that because then you have nothing for `\1` to match against..

Comment: Thanks @MartijnPieters , I didn't see your post yet when writing my comment :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using groups in a regular expression, `findall()` returns only the groups; from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall):

> If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

You can't avoid using groups when using backreferences, but you *can* put a new group around the whole pattern:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"((\b\w+)\s+\2)")
>>> p.findall("I am in the the car.")
[('the the', 'the')]
```

The outer group is group 1, so the backreference should be pointing to group 2. You now have *two* groups, so there are two results per entry. Using a named group might make this more readable:

```
>>> p = re.compile(r"((?P<word>\b\w+)\s+(?P=word))")
```

You can filter that back to just the outer group result:

```
>>> [m[0] for m in p.findall("I am in the the car.")]
['the the']
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you Martijn :-)